# Inserting a node at given position

Tags: c, linked-list

Node is not getting inserted at position. I am new to coding and working on linked list.here head is pointing to start which i have declared globally.please help me to modify the code

```
void insert_at_position(struct node **head, int x, int pos)
{
    struct node *temp,*t,*tails = *head;
    t = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (start == NULL)
    {
        start = t;
        start->data = x;
        start->next = NULL;
        return;
    }
    count++;
    while (temp->next!=NULL)
    {
        tails = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
        if (i == pos)
        {
            tails->next=t;
            t->data=x;
            t->next=temp->next;
            return;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your *temp pointer is always pointing to NULL. This may depend on your compiler but the one I am using does not initialize all variables to *head with the syntax you are using.

Comment: There are multiple issues in this code. For the statement "if (start == NULL)", where is start defined ?

Comment: Please provide [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/) sample code

Answer (score 0):

1. What's the use of count variable and why is `i` not declared anywhere? Please correct it.
2. Inside your `while` condition you need to handle `pos == 0` case-
3. Below code will work

---

```
int insertNode(int pos, int data)
{
    struct node *temp = NULL, *tails = NULL, *p = NULL;
    p = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    p->data = data;
    p->next = NULL;
    if(pos == 0)
    {
        p->next = start;
        start = p;
        return 0;
    }
    temp = tails = start;

    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
        pos--;

        if(pos == 0)
        {
            tails->next = p;
            p->next = temp;
            return 0;
        }
        tails = tails->next;
    }

    if(pos)
        printf("\nError!!! Invalid position, can't insert\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The one problem in your code is that the `temp` is not initialized so the `temp->next` will not point to next node do `temp = *head` during declaration.
2. i is not declared.
3. If start is NULL you are inserting new node to pos=0 position regardless of position given as parameter(`pos`) to the function.
4. In your code a new node will not be added to `pos=0` when number of nodes in linked list is 1(only head node).
5. In your code the new node will only be inserted to `pos+1` position and not `pos`. During while loop iteration when `i == pos` condition is met tails points to the node at position 2 so you should have been inserting the node between tails_pervious node and tails node but you are inserting it between tails and tails_next which is incorrect.

---

The below code can be used. The code has only few modifications from the original code(so that you can understant your mistakes easily).

```
void insert_at_position(struct node **head, int x, int pos)
{
  struct node *temp = *head,*t,*tails = *head;  //temp was not initialized in original code so temp->next will not point to next node.
  int i = 0; // i was not initialized in original code
  t=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  if(t == NULL) // malloc fail case check
  {
      return;
  }
  if (pos == 0) // 0th position insertion handling section
  {
      t->data = x;
      t->next = start;
      start = t;
      return;
  }
  if(start == NULL) // It is better to not inset any node if  position != 0 and Start == NULL
  {
      free(t);  // If the node is not inserted free the allocated memory.
      return;
  }
  count++;    // Assuming count is an global variable
  while(temp != NULL)
  {
      tails = temp;    
      temp = temp->next;
      if(i+1 == pos) // In this case tails points to the previous location
      {
          tails->next=t;
          t->data=x;
          t->next=temp; // temp now points to the node that was originally at 'pos' position
          return;
      }
      i++;          
  }
  free(t);  // If the node is not inserted free the allocated memory.
}
```

But I would like to suggest some improvements:-

- It is better to use a return type for the function so that the caller function can check if the operation is successful.
- It is always a good programming practice to reduce the exit points in a function i.e try to reduce the return statements inside a function. You can easily negotiate the use of return statement with the use of few if-else checks(it is totaly worth it)

Answer (score 0):

- dont allocate before you need it
- use the power of the pointer-to pointer
- handle the case of inserting at the top (pos =0)
- handle the case where pos > length of the list

---

```
void insert_at_position(struct node **head, int x, int pos)
{
    struct node *new;

    if (!head) { // defensive
          return;
          }

        // Walk the list, until we
        // reach the end
        // or we have passed 'pos' nodes
    for (       ; *head; head = &(*head)->next) {
        if (!pos) break;
        pos --;
        }

     if (pos) { // list too short
        return;
        }

    new = malloc (sizeof *new);
     if (!new) { // malloc failed
        return;
        }
    new->data = x;
    new->next = *head;
    *head = new;
}
```